# android-studio : Error while executing studio.sh

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

After attending Google IO 2016 extended, I downloaded studio from https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/2.2.0.0/android-studio-ide-145.2878421-linux.zip

I extracted it. But after that, I am not able to execute studio.sh..

It shows following error:

```
To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~/Applications/android-studio/bin$ ./studio.sh 
./studio.sh: 137: ./studio.sh: declare: not found
./studio.sh: 141: ./studio.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

Am I missing something ?

**Note:** I have posted the issue on Google Plus Community [Android Studio](https://plus.google.com/communities/103491657963571270604). Hers's the [Link to my post](https://plus.google.com/+ChintanSoni201188/posts/RXEWACxtGDw)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use the previous studio.sh file and it works like a charm!

Comment: You just saved my day. It works like a charm indeed. I get no errors

Answer (score 60):

If you are ubuntu user then you can edit studio.sh and change fist line from

```
#!/bin/sh
```

to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

It works for me in Ubuntu 14.04.

[Original Issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210256)

Comment: The perfect answer

Answer (score 4):

Edit the file `~/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`:

change line 1

```
#!/bin/sh
```

to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: Someone else said the exact same thing 14 hours before you, what does your answer add?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed in Android Studio 2.2 preview 2 (download from [this page](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-2-preview-2)).

> Fixed bug preventing the IDE from starting on some Linux distributions (in particular where /bin/sh is not bash)

From the [changelog](http://tools.android.com/recent).

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error and i have replaced the latest **/bin/studio.sh** file with my previous **/bin/studio.sh** file and it works like charm.